# Why extremely tiny (but still visible with the naked eyes) objects do not quantum tunnel?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-interpretations, quantum-tunneling, decoherence

What is the reason that we don't see such objects quantum tunnel? Decoherence? If YES, at what "level" does the decoherence completely suppress quantum tunnelling? Where is the "threshold"?

One can easily hold that we are living in a quantum world (since everything is constituted by atomic and subatomic particles). In that case, however, one must be ready to explain why the macroscopic world appears classical.

On the other hand, we can't ignore the aspect of vanishingly small probabilities of "raw" QM events being observed in complex macroscopic objects (as QM theory predicts, and IF the theory is valid for such objects).However, Given that there are so many different objects in the world (visible with the naked eye: from a grain of sand to a ping pong ball and so on) and given that so many different people have lived on the Earth and are living up to now…  isn’t it likely that someone must have observed tunnelling of a visible object?

P.S.
By "seeing" I don't mean "interaction between quantum object and environment"; just the common, the first meaning of the word.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing implicitly means bombarding it with photons that then hit your eye. That's a pretty big and noisey system. With that being said there have been macroscopic objects in quantum superpositioin.

[Physicist in California made a tuning fork of sorts vibrate and not vibrate](https://physicsworld.com/a/quantum-effect-spotted-in-a-visible-object/)
[image: tuning fork]

" an object so large in fact that it can just about be seen with the naked eye. The object is a mechanical resonator made of aluminium and aluminium nitride, measuring about 40 µm in length"

Comment: vibrate and not vibrate of course being an approximation of the level of excitement of the state